# TextField can't be resized within RowLayout

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

After putting `TextField` in `RowLayout` I can't resize the `TextField` anymore. I tried to set `anchor`s for `TextField` to fill left side of `RowLayout` and its center to make it the half of `width` of the `RowLayout` but it becames just bigger than the half of it.

Right now I'm trying to bind the `width` of the `TextField` to that of `RowLayout` but still the element just doesn't resize. When I take `TextField` out of its parent it resizes fine. Is this a bug of `Qt` or did I forget something?

Here is the pic of what I get:

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 210
    height: 160

    RowLayout {
        x: 15
        y: 21
        width: 181
        height: 23

        TextField {
            id: first
            width: parent.width /2
            height: parent.height
        }

        TextField {
            id: second
            width: parent.width /2
            height: parent.height
        }
    }

    TextField {
        id: result
        x: 15
        y: 55
        width: 181
        height: 23
        placeholderText: qsTr("Result")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not considering `spacing` which by default isn't zero. Also, `anchors.fill: parent` the layout: setting `x`/`y` like that is bad design.

Comment: Write your own answer. My rule for RowLayout/ColumnLayout is to not to use width/height. Only use implicitWidth/implicitHeight, Layout.fillWidth, Layout.preferredWidth, Layout.minimumWidth, etc.

Comment: Last thing: when RowLayout really-really turns against you, wrap it into an Item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @KernelPanic said, I used `Layout.fillWidth` on `TextField`s and everything began to work fine.

According to Qt documentation:

> If this property is true, the item will be as wide as possible while respecting the given constraints. If the property is false, the item will have a fixed width set to the preferred width. The default is false, except for layouts themselves, which default to true.

And

> respecting the given constraints

was exactly what I needed